# How is the isomorphism between a vector space and its dual not natural?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$ and $V^*=\mathcal{L}(V,K)$ its dual space. We can prove that $V$ is *naturally* isomorphic to its double dual $V^{**}$, but why does every isomorphism between $V$ and its dual $V^*$ depend on the choice of basis? We certainly use dual basis, but the number of element of a basis i.e. the dimension is not basis-dependent. For example, in *Linear Algebra* by *Serge Lang*, I have found this:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ with a non-degenerate scalar product, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\rightarrow K$. Let $v\in V$, the map $L_v$ such that
\begin{equation}
V\ni u\overset{L_v}{\longrightarrow}\langle u,v\rangle
\end{equation}
is a linear functional, thus an element of $V^*$.

The map such that
\begin{equation}
V\ni v\rightarrow L_v
\end{equation}
is an isomorphism (between $V$ and its dual).
This is proved by showing that this map is linear, injective (because of non-degeneracy) and surjective ($dimV=dimV^*$).
So, how does this depend on the choice of basis? It is true that we used the dual basis at the beginning, but as I said above, every basis would give us the same answer as for the dimension of the space, that is  what the author used in the last proof.

Comment: Yes, if you fix an inner product you get an isomorphism between the space and its dual.  However, there is no natural choice of inner product on a vector space.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the fact this isomorphism is not natural is not because of the dual basis but because of the scalar product?

Comment: I didn't mention a basis.  I'm just saying that you got your isomorphism by adding structure, so there was nothing natural about it.

Comment: May be it's time to define what is natural...

Comment: Given any basis $\beta = \{ v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ there is an unique inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_\beta$ which makes that basis orthonormal. The set of inner product is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of basis.

Comment: @ArcticCharonstrike I don't think there is a one-to-one correspondence. On $\mathbb R^2$, if $A$ is a rotation by a fixed angle, then both $\{e_1, e_2\}$ and $\{A e_1, A e_2\}$ are both orthonormal bases with regard to the standard inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not natural because the identification between elements of the vector space and its dual depend upon the basis and, importantly, the correspondence is not maintained upon a change of basis. The latter is easiest to see by thinking about how the components of vectors and convectors change in opposite senses under a change of basis. In your case, note that your map defines dual vectors with respect to the basis dual to that of the original space which is a basis dependent identification.

This is not the case for the correspondence between the dual of the dual and the original space, where a basis-independent identification can be made. In this way, although (for finite dim vector spaces) any vector space of the same dimension is equivalent to the original space, the identification $(V^*)^* \cong V$ is natural because everyone will agree on the correspondence between vectors regardless of the basis they're using.